# how to verify list of check box present on webpage or not

Tags: selenium

from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='../drivers/chromedriver')

#implicit wait time

driver.implicitly_wait(5)

#url launch

driver.get("https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/checkboxes")

#identify element

l = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='checkbox']")

l.click()

if l.is_selected():

print('Checkbox is checked')

else:

print('Checkbox is not checked')

#close driver

driver.close()

Comment: Question title is _to verify list of check box present on webpage or not_, where as your attempt is validating `is_selected()` through `if`. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

```
Maven dependancy : 
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0</version>
        </dependency> 
**********************************


WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver()`enter code here`;
        driver.get("https://demo.anhtester.com/basic-checkbox-demo.html");
        // Xpath mention in the below line can be vary  
        List<WebElement> lst = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@type='checkbox']/.."));
    
        
        // In this for loop I am listing the name of all the checkbox present on page
        // We can perform other operations on Web Element 
        for(int i=0;i<lst.size();i++) {
            System.out.println(lst.get(i).getText());
        }
```